# Is there any advantage of using jquery $(window).width(); and height functions over window.resizeTo( w,h )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just wondering 
if there are any advantages of using jquery

```
$(window).width(); 
$(window).height();
```

to change the browser's dimension over

```
window.resizeTo( w,h );
```

if you going to change them both anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, but `window.resizeTo( w,h );` is shorter.

Comment: thats what i thought ... i wanted to use it but i wondered if there were any advantages to the jquery version :) thx